# Can i delete a single data point in OpenTSDB

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I am using OpenTSDB to store my time series data, but if I want to delete any data point, I am not able to find a right solution, if I go according to their documentation, the data for that whole hour also gets deleted, which is not exactly serving the purpose, Do anyone know of any other way.

Comment: If you can't delete the sample, can you override its value with NaN by inserting NaN with the same timestamp?

Comment: Tried, not updating when I put the query

Comment: You can insert some other value with the same timestamp to check that value overwrite is supported at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do so via a **/query** and instruct OpenTSDB to delete the queried data.

According to OpenTSDB latest documentation:

```
delete  Boolean Optional    Can be passed to the JSON with a POST to delete any data points that match the given query. false       W   true
```

To do so, either:

1. query but using verb `DELETE`
2. `POST` with a delete=true in your json body

Examples

```
{
    "start": 1356998400,
    "end": 1356998460,
    "delete": true,
    "queries": [
        {
            "aggregator": "sum",
            "metric": "sys.cpu.0",
            "rate": "true",
            "tags": {
                "host": "*",
                "dc": "lga"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Reference: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html

Comment: This question aged well, this was not there when I asked. However, thanks for answering, might help other people looking for same.